# Undefined index html to php

Tags: php, html

I am not getting any output at all once I enter the details and click on the Register button and being a beginner in php I can't figure out what it is that I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["Register"])) {
$name = $_POST["Name"];
$email = $_POST["Email_Address"];
$uname = $_POST["Email_Address"];
$password = $_POST["Password"];

echo $name;
}
?>
```

The html file is as follows:

```
    <form action="register.php" method"POST">

    Name: <br>
    <input type="text" name="Name" required><br>
    <br>
    Email Address: <br>
    <input type="email" name="Email_Address" required><br>
    <br>
    Set Password: <br>
    <input type="password" name="Password" required><br>
    <br>
    Confirm Password:
    <input type="password" name="CPassword" required><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="Register">
    </form>

</div>
```

Also worth mentioning here is the fact that I have another similar form on the same page with a different name to the submit input. So I don't think that is the reason why I am not getting the output. I believe that the Register button is never being set but I wonder why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these

```
<form action="register.php" method"POST">
```

To these

```
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
```

You forgot about `=`

Answer (score 0):

By default `input` elements with `type="submit"` are not sent along via `POST` requests. Therefore `isset($_POST['Register'])` always evaluates to false, and your code is not being run hence no output.

One possible solution would be to add an extra hidden `input` to your form like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" />
```

This will be sent along with the `POST` request, where you can check `isset($_POST['action'])` in your PHP and you should get the desired behaviour.

Comment: It's exactly passes everything that in the form. :)